# How to start a project from git template preserving sub-modules

Tags: git

All the guide I've found allow to clone a template and just re-init Git in order to lose all the history. But this will kill all the submodule repository.

Is there any way to start a new project from a template preserving sub-modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
git checkout --orphan clone master
git commit -m 'initial checkin'
```

you will create a new branch `clone` with an empty history.  This operation preserves the submodule state.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git rebase -i --root` and change "pick" to "squash" for every commit except the first and change the message to something appropriate. This will squash all of your commits into one. This will allow you to "lose your history" (or clean it up at the very least) and preserve your sub-modules.